# How to add dictionary values (list type) to an excel file with the key being the row number?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
  1: ['hello', 'hi', 'greeings']
  2: ['john', 'david']
  3: ['foo', 'fee', 'faa', 'fii']
}
```

and I would like to create a new column with name 'test' and add each list value to the corresponding row number.

for example, this how the excel will look like:

```
old column | ... | test
--------------------------------------------
some data  | ... | hello, hi, greetings
some data  | ... | john, david
some data  | ... | foo, fee, faa, fii
```

**EDIT**

The excel file already exists and I can successfully read it, I want to add a new column to it

Comment: Do you have an attempt?

Comment: Do you want to use `.xls/.xlsx` or just want to open generated file of other type in  excel?

Comment: Not really, as i do not know how to iterate excel rows and add to them

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus use .xls/.xlsx

Comment: Do you not know how to load the Excel file into Pandas? Because that's a separate matter from `pd.concat([file, pd.Series(your_dict, name='test')], axis=1)`

Comment: @ifly6 yes I am already reading the data using pandas `df = pd.read_excel(fileName)`

Comment: @Abdane then i can't help with exact exmple, sorry. But i suggest you to read [this](https://www.kindsonthegenius.com/blog/2018/01/how-to-connect-python-to-excel-read-and-write-data-try-it.html). Or make `csv` file out of your data and open it in excel, i did it in libreoffice. Works like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the index and return into your new column the mapped values of dict.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
your_dict = {0: 'ha', 1: 'blah', 2: 'hah', 3: ['foo', 'bar']}

df['mapped'] = df.index.map(your_dict)
```

The data I'm using was loaded from the last example dataframe that was in memory. Reloading was unnecessary:

```
df
Out[42]: 
    Name  Age  Height  Hair_Width      mapped
0    Tom   20      23          21          ha
1   nick   21      43          11        blah
2  krish   19     123          23         hah
3   jack   18      12          14  [foo, bar]
```

---

The original method I put in my comment was:

```
ndf = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(your_dict, name='test')], axis=1)
ndf
Out[46]: 
    Name  Age  Height  Hair_Width      mapped        test
0    Tom   20      23          21          ha          ha
1   nick   21      43          11        blah        blah
2  krish   19     123          23         hah         hah
3   jack   18      12          14  [foo, bar]  [foo, bar]

assert (ndf.mapped == ndf.test).all()  # no err
```

Comment: Instead of using a `lambda`, why not just use `df.index.map(your_dict)`, which will fill missing values with `nan`.  It's also preferable to your second solution.

Comment: TIL something new ^

Comment: Thank you, `df['mapped'] = df.index.map(your_dict)` worked perfectly :)